# Running .exe file using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am running below powershell script: It has .exe file to run by taking input file and write into output file. But, I dont see output file is written anything when executing script.

Input file has list of queries which will be executed by srvrmgr.exe file

```
#Input File
$InputFile = "C:\Siebel\SiebelInput.txt"

#Output File
$OutputFile = "C:\Siebel\siebelOutput.txt"

#command Siebel
$BatchFileCommand = "C:\Siebel\siebsrvr\BIN\srvrmgr.exe /g SblGateway /e ENT_17 /u SADMIN /p xxxx /i $InputFile /o $OutputFile"
```

Can you please help me if something is missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your last command merely assigns the string to the variable `$batchFileCommand`. Try something like this:

```
& "C:\Siebel\siebsrvr\BIN\srvrmgr.exe" /g SblGateway /e ENT_17 /u SADMIN /p xxxx /i $InputFile /o $OutputFile
```